# A proof that P != NP

Tags: algorithms, halting-problem

I came up with the following. Am I doing something wrong?

Suppose $P=NP$. Let $A$ be an NP hard problem. Let $A'$ be the polynomial reduction of $A$. By the assumtions, the Halting problem holts for $A$. Let $T'$ be the running time of $A'$. Clearly, $T' \in O(P(n))$, with $n$ as input size for $A'$ and $P(n)$ representing the class of polynomial functions of $n$. By that, the running time of $A'$ is bounded above and since it is a polynomial reduction of $A$, the running time of $A$ should also be bounded above. By that, there exists an algorithm, namely $X():=$return $True;$ which is a solution to the Halting problem for $A$. By that, the Halting problem does not hold for $A$, which is a contradiction. So the assumption that $P=NP$ can not hold and therefore $P \neq NP$.

Comment: Just a pointer - any NP hard problem will halt on any input: this is because it has a finite number of solutions to check. The halting problem does not discuss poly-time, but rather finite time.

Comment: You are claiming to have a solution for a well-known, difficult open problem. This is [an extraordinary claim requiring extraordinary evidence](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marcello_Truzzi#.22Extraordinary_claims.22). You have not provided such so there is not much to talk about. Even if you had, this would not be a good post for SE; it is not our goal here to make broad advances to science in a single post. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/109/how-to-deal-with-questions-about-crank-heavy-topics) for a related discussion.

Comment: I have doubts on whether $A'$ is bonded, could be a misunderstanding though, and also, here is a list of proofs that claims solved P versus NP: http://www.win.tue.nl/~gwoegi/P-versus-NP.htm , the list is quite famous, half of them gotta be wrong right?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Let $A$ be an NP hard problem

The halting problem, among others, is $NP$-hard. Did you mean to pick a $NP$-complete problem instead?

> Let $A'$ be the polynomial reduction of $A$.

What is "the polynomial reduction", where is it defined? Reduction to/from *what*? Do you mean that $A'$ is a polynomial algorithm that solves $A$? (Which would exist by virtue of your $P=NP$ assumption and $A$ being in $NP$.)

> the Halting problem holts for $A$

What does it mean for the Halting problem to holt (hold?) for $A$? The halting problem isn't parameterized on any particular program.

> the running time of $A$ should also be bounded above

$A$ does not have a running time. It is a problem, not an algorithm.

> There exists an algorithm [...] is a solution to the Halting problem for $A$

For any program $P$ there is an algorithm that computes whether or not $P$ halts. Namely, the algorithm that trivially returns one of true/false. The Halting Problem doesn't state that there can be no algorithm that computes whether a particular program halts, but rather that there is no algorithm that is correct for *all* programs.